# Not able to put aggregated data into memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to put aggregated data into memory but getting error.Any suggestion ??

> > > orders = spark.read.json("/user/order_items_json")
> > >
> > > df_2 = orders.where("order_item_order_id == 2").groupby("order_item_order_id")
> > >
> > > df_2.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'persist'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark requires **aggregation** expression on grouped data.

If you don't need any aggregations on the grouped data then we can have some dummy aggregation like **first,count...etc** and drop the column from `.select` like below:

```
import pyspark

df_2 = orders.where("order_item_order_id == 2").groupby("order_item_order_id").agg(first(lit("1"))).select("order_item_order_id")
#or
df_2 = orders.where("order_item_order_id == 2").groupby("order_item_order_id").count().select("order_item_order_id")

df_2.persist(pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Shu....I also realized that I missed function.... Thank you so much for prompt response.

Comment: Hi Shu , I didn't understand where I need to click to close this thread.